# In RabbitMQ, How to make Queues in different clusters to Be Highly Available without Clustering?

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, high-availability

In RabbitMQ, if two clusters are hosted on geographical different locations, then we can’t use Clustering. Then how to make them highly available I.e. if one site’s whole cluster goes down then the messages should be mirrored to other site and other site should be able to cater those messages. Note : sites are connected by WAN

See I can’t lose any message on the both sites. Publishing message to the right site can be taken care of, but if the messages are in queue(work queue) or messages are being processed by consumer and suddenly if the site goes down which includes the broker and consumer, how can those messages be catered by the other site. Like in a cluster if one node dies, the other one has all the messages mirrored and knows which were acknowledged, but how to achieve this on WAN, cause clustering cross WAN is not practical.

Comment: You might just have to publish twice... but there really aren't enough details here to be able to help you.

Comment: If I publish twice using federated exchange, and one site acknowledges it, how will the other site know that message was acknowledged.  Or should I use some other strategy?

Comment: I am not entirely sure the use case makes sense. Publish twice in the sense that your first publish fails, so you publish to the failover? I'm not sure, as I said, the question is rather vague.

Comment: Added some more information, if you need more info, kindly let me know

Comment: If my queue is mirrored then I don’t need to publish twice, so how can I mirror queue without Clustering the nodes. [as the nodes are on different sites]

Comment: I don’t think you can safely mirror across a WAN. Erlang is very sensitive to network latency and partitions.

Comment: So there is no way of queue mirroring across two diff clusters through WAN..?? May be Kafka can provide such solution

Comment: I would think the [Shovel plug in](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) could offer some help there. From reading your question, however, I really suspect you have a design problem. It seems like you're expecting the message broker to be the silver bullet to the fault tolerance problem, when really it is the system architecture that provides for this.

Comment: I have tried shovel plugin, it can help in load balancing between sites but won’t help much in fail over. See, for design all I want is disaster recovery for messages. System arch is mostly recoverable for data , but broker has to take care of in flight messages I.e. messages in queue waiting to be served and messages in consumer not acknowledged yet. Basically Active Active sites are needed.

Comment: OK, well that is the problem then. Messages are not meant to be things you generally care about in terms of disaster recovery. A proper deign would be able to pick up where it left off in terms of message processing, re-generating any messages necessary to reconstruct the state. Also, I don't understand your remark about Shovel. It seems that you may have missed some of the documentation on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question illustrates a conceptual problem with the design. To summarize,

1. There are two sites, connected via WAN
2. One site is the primary, while one is the active standby
3. There is a desire for complete replication of system state (total consistency) between site A and B, to include the status of messages in the queue and messages being processed.

Essentially, you want 100% consistency, availability, and partition tolerance. Such a design is not possible according to [CAP Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).  What RabbitMQ provides is either consistency and availability, with low partition tolerance via [clustering](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html), or availability and partition tolerance via [federation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html) or [shovel](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html).  RabbitMQ does not deal very well with the case of needing consistency and partition tolerance, since message brokers really handle highly transient traffic.

Instead, what is needed is to fully scope the problem to something that can be solved using the available technologies. It sounds to me like the correct approach (since it's over a WAN) is to sacrifice availability for consistency and partition tolerance, and have your application handle the failover case.   You may be able to configure RabbitMQ sufficiently in this regard - see https://www.rabbitmq.com/partitions.html.